# how to select the latest (by date) documents filtered by criteria (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

Given the example collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88a"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:00:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor1", "metric" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88b"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:01:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor1", "metric" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88c"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:02:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor1", "metric" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88d"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:03:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor2", "metric" : 20 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88e"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:04:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor2", "metric" : 21 }
```

I'm looking to build a query that would return the following: (assume I can inject the set of sensors. e.g. `{ $in: ["sensor1", "sensor2"] }`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88c"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:02:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor1", "metric" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59db7bd22f02828b587ca88e"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T07:04:00Z"), "sensor" : "sensor2", "metric" : 21 }
```

Those two documents represent the latest for each `sensor`. I could do it with two queries, one for each sensor:

```
db.readings.find({"sensor": "sensor1"}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1)
db.readings.find({"sensor": "sensor2"}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1)
```

But I would like to understand if it could be done as one query. Again, the only data I have available to me is the set of sensors. While the above example query is limited to returning one document, ideally I would like to ask for `n` readings, so the set of documents coming back would always be `n` within each sensor.

### Update

I can use the aggregation framework as mentioned in the comments below, but I can only get one. i.e.`{$first:"$$ROOT"}`. I would like to get `n` documents, so something like `{$push:"$$ROOT", $limit:2}` would be great, but that doesn't exist. Are there alternatives?

Comment: You can do it with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) request.

Comment: Something like this should work. `db.readings.aggregate([{$match:{"sensor": { $in: ["sensor1", "sensor2"] }}}, {$sort:{sensor:1,date:-1}}, {$group:{_id:"$sensor", data:{$first:"$$ROOT"}}} ])`